# Webbrowser control - Consolo.log javascript error

Tags: javascript, webbrowser-control, console.log

I would like to develop an add-in for MS Excel. I need to use Webbrowser control to display some websites such as https://depmap.org/rnai/genedeps?gene=AKT3. However, webbrowser control uses IE11 to render web site. IE11 cannot properly load web-site and display graphs, because of the "console.log()" error. In IE11 if you try to navigate to this page, it only properly when "Developer tools" is open. This issue was described here: [Site behaves differently when developer tools are open IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685216/site-behaves-differently-when-developer-tools-are-open-ie11)

Regarding this issue, all suggestion were on modifying the javascript. Since I cant modify these web pages I need to find another way to open these web pages through webbrowser control.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: I have a suggestion. There is a registry entry that can be set to force a web browser control instance whether in an app, outlook, or excel to use IE11 standards. Without that, the web browser control will default to IE7 or 8. In some cases an XUA meta comparability tag can bring it up to IE11 as well, but not everyone has control over what is website is being displayed. Have you tried using this registry entry, or is deploying a registry change as part of installing your excel addon not a viable solution? Or have you tried inject the meta XUA compatibility tag into pages dynamically?

Comment: That meta tag for reference is : <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: And this blog covers how the registry entry works. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version